# How to disable text replacement in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, textformfield

I have some text replacements registered from General -> Keyboard -> Text Replacement. I want to prevent auto text replacement in some of my fields inside my app.

autocorrect: false & enableSuggestions: false does not work.

```
Form(
                  child: TextFormField(

                      validator: (value) {
                        if (widget.arguments.isNumber) {
                          return Validators.weightValidator(value, context);
                        }

                        return Validators.emptyValidator(value, context);
                      },                       
                      keyboardType: widget.arguments.isNumber
                          ? const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                              decimal: true)
                          : TextInputType.text,
                      obscureText: false,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      controller: _controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "kg",
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ))),
                  key: _formKey,
                ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To prevent users from copying or pasting text in a TextFormField, you can create a custom class that extends MaterialTextSelectionControls. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
class NoCopyTextSelectionControls extends MaterialTextSelectionControls 
{
  @override
  bool canCopy(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) => false;

  @override
  bool canCut(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) => false;

  @override
  bool canPaste(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) => false;

  @override
  bool canSelectAll(TextSelectionDelegate delegate) => false;
}
```

Now, to use this custom class in your TextFormField to disable text copying and pasting, do the following:

```
TextFormField(
  // Pass the custom class instance to selectionControls
  selectionControls: NoCopyTextSelectionControls(),
  // Other properties for your TextFormField
)
```

By passing the NoCopyTextSelectionControls instance to selectionControls, you are essentially replacing the default text selection controls with your custom controls, which disable copying, cutting, pasting, and selecting all text in the TextFormField.

Comment: This is not working for me. The text is being replaced regardless of selection options.

Comment: I've already tested this on my real-time device, and it appears to be functioning properly. Could you kindly provide more information about your code and how you are using TextFormField in your code? Also, tell me which design theme you are using - Material or Cupertino? If you are using Cupertino then replace **MaterialTextSelectionControls** with **CupertinoTextSelectionControls** in your NoCopyTextSelectionControls class.

Comment: I have updated my question to include the code.